# SVN Pre-commit Symbolic Link Path in Perl

Tags: linux, svn, unix, symlink

In my workplace, there's one Perl script that runs on a Unix machine every time someone tries to check-in a file to the SVN repo for any of the 10-20 projects.

The way it works is that each project has its own "Hooks" folder with a file called "pre-commit" which SVN automatically executes when someone check-in something. Except the "pre-commit" file is actually a symbolic link to the one central Perl script common to all projects just so that if a change needs to be made to the Perl script it doesn't need to be done for every project.

So my problem is this: I need to put a text file in each of these projects' "hooks" directory, each one containing some settings specific to that project. So there will be 10-20 settings files (one per project) each in their respective "hooks" directory.

The problem is that I need to open these text files in the Perl script and read from them but I'm having issues letting Perl know where to find it. I tried using the $0 parameter which is supposed to tell me where the script is being executed from but because it's a symbolic link it just says "Not a directory" and the script terminates. I need to get the path of the "hooks" directory so that I can find the text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SVN pre-commit script is supposed to be invoked with the path to the repository as its first argument.  Inside a Perl script, that argument should be available as `$ARGV[0]`.  You should be able to build the path to the corresponding **hooks** directory or to a file inside that directory by simply appending to the repository path, like this:

```
$repopath = $ARGV[0];
$hookspath = $repopath . "/hooks";
$myfilepath = $hookspath . "/myfile";
```

although for maximum portability it would be cleaner to use the pathname-manipulation functions in the File::Spec module to do this.

If this approach doesn't work then you'll have to explain more about how your Perl script gets invoked.  For instance, if your pre-commit script is really a shell script wrapper that eventually invokes `perl` then perhaps it's not passing the pre-commit arguments along properly.

Showing us your current code that's failing would be a good thing too.